# Custom Timer to get the seconds to the next start time/date

Tags: python, date, time, timer

I have a project where I have assigned certain days of the week to be running, while other days that are not included should be skipped. Eg:

Days On: Mon (0), Tues (1), Wed (2), Thurs (3), Fri (4) 
Days Off: Sat (5), Sun (6)

I have settings saved within the registry for the days on, when the settings are pulled they are referenced by their weekday number.

If I want to put my app to sleep on Fri (4), and have it wake up on Mon (0), how can I go about doing so? I have no way to state for sure whether the days off will be consistent, might have Sun/Mon off instead of Sat/Sun.

Ideally I need to look at the current weekday number, see if it is within the list of days on and if not, have it calculate the number of seconds until the next day on begins.

Scenarios:

1. I set my script to go to sleep on Friday June 8th, and Sat/Sun are off days, how do I calculate the seconds to sleep for those two days so that it starts again on Mon 11th?
2. I set my script to go to sleep on Wed June 6th, and I need it to wake up on Fri June 8th, but then turn it back off on Friday night to have it start again on Monday morning.

because the days on are variable, this function must be able to accommodate for it; which is where I am running into my problems.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, big thanks in advance!

Comment: Which platform are you on, or is this supposed to be universal in that regard? I'd say this is a `cron` job on *nix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check once a day - if today is not an On day, go back to sleep until tomorrow.

OR

Use `cron` (or Windows Task Scheduler) to schedule the program for the needed days.

OR

```
import datetime
from time import sleep

SECONDS_PER_DAY = 3600 * 24
DAILY_START_TIME = datetime.time(8,15)   # 8:15 am

def seconds(t):
    return 3600*t.hour + 60*t.minute + t.second

def now():
    t = datetime.datetime.now()
    return t.weekday(), seconds(t)

def load_run_days():
    # get data from registry
    return [1,1,1,1,1,0,0]

def days_until_next_run(today, run_days=None):
    if run_days is None:
        run_days = load_run_days()
    # rotate
    run_days = run_days[today+1:] + run_days[:today+1]
    # find next On day
    for days,_on in enumerate(run_days, 1):
        if _on:
            return days
    # no run day found?
    raise ValueError("No 'On' days found")

def sleep_until_next_run():
    today, elapsed = now()
    days_to_wait = days_until_next_run(today)
    sleep(-elapsed + days_to_wait*SECONDS_PER_DAY + seconds(DAILY_START_TIME))

def main():
    while True:
        try:
            sleep_until_next_run()
        except ValueError:
            break

        do_my_stuff()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Assume this is retrieved from registry
runningOn[0] = True # Monday
runningOn[1] = True
runningOn[2] = True
runningOn[3] = True
runningOn[4] = True
runningOn[5] = True
runningOn[6] = True # Sunday

# Get current day of week
import datetime
currentDayOfWeek = datetime.datetime.now().weekday()

# How much time should we sleep?
sleepDays = 1 # at least a day
for i in range(1, 6):
    if runningOn[(i + currentDayOfWeek) % 7]:
        break
    sleepDays += 1

# Run code, if necessary
if runningOn[currentDayOfWeek]:
    doWhatever()

# Sleep
sleep(sleepDays * 24 * 3600)
```